# RobotFramework hangs after xx lines of log

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, robotframework

Robot framework keeps hanging on me when I try to execute a simple python script, it stales for no reason at about 30th line of log generated and no matter how long I wait it does not progress.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Windows ? If yes, it has nothing to do with RF itself, its a windows "feature" and as your answer points out, logging into a file is a workaround ..

Comment: No, I've tested it on linux

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is simple!

Just log to file directly from Python instead of relying on the Robot framework.